# Opinions on this authentication with a different server in a RESTful architecture

Tags: performance, security, authentication, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I' new in implementing a RESTful web service. I need your opinion to understand if my idea can work. I want take separate the authentication database from the resources database (the main one, with all the user stories). I put them in two different web servers. The clients ask their token to this primary interface (the auth server) that replies the generated token (if login is valid) and at the same time the authentication server sends the userID and userToken to the resources database server.

The client has received the token, it means it's logged in and it can makes requestes of resources to the resources database server. It appends its userToken to prove its identity. The resources database server checks the userToken and if it's not expired, it replies with the requested data to the client.

I've tried to explain the concept with two images.

I would like to understand if this is a good implementation of an authentication process. I really care about the **security**, **performance** and **flexibility**. What do you think about this?

[image: The client wants to authenticate itself and generates its own token]
[image: The client is now logged in and can makes requests of resources]

Do you have any suggestions related on this? Thank you very much.